# Do I need to uninstall ROS (raspberry pi 3)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all -

So, I installed ROS on my pi recently following the installation tutorial.  Installation was successful and I can use ROS to print hello and post topics (verified).

When I attempt to run:

> **sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-tutorials**

I get the error  **E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-tutorials**

I figure this is because I installed the the wrong packages using the ROS-Comm build that doesn't support GUI tools.  I believe I should of used the Desktop build to get package support for things like turtlesim.  So, I tried to re-install Desktop over my existing ROS-Comm version, but with no success.

1. Is my assumption correct and the reason I'm getting the "unable to locate package" error due to having installed the wrong version of indigo?
2. Must I completely uninstall ROS and start over, or is there another way to do this by removing certain packages before attempting to recompile?

Thanks all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238923/do-i-need-to-uninstall-ros-(raspberry-pi-3)?/) by [Nate](https://answers.ros.org/users/27411/nate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. I don't think the version of indigo matters when trying to install a specific package (that package might just be unavailable to raspberry pi 3
2. I'm not sure about reinstalling, are you running this on rasbian? ubuntu arm? I'm most familiar with running the Ubuntu arm on raspberry pi, and if I'm not mistaken, ros Indigo has some packages that raspberry pi 3 doesn't like. Some other people have had success with it (I just stuck with raspberry pi 2 to use indigo) but maybe these links will help, looks like the first one used debian jesse. Hope these help!

http://answers.ros.org/question/230076/ros-on-raspberry-3/

http://answers.ros.org/question/231216/cant-install-ros-on-raspberry-pi-3/

---

Originally posted by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) with karma: 261 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0